# Como cambiar el color de las lineas en un diagrama de Venn (ggVennDiagram function)

Tags: r

Estoy realizando un diagrama de Venn que acorde con el número de conteos aparece de un color u otro. Para ello he utilizado el siguiente código:

```
     ggVennDiagram(
       x, label_alpha = 0,
       category.names = c("Cough","Sputum","Dyspnea", "Wheezing"),
       color = c('orange', 'green', 'blue','red')
     ) +
       ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient(low="white",high = "grey")
```

Obteniendo el siguiente gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo quiero que las lineas aparezcan acorde con el color que les he marcado y no con el que aparecen en el gráfico. Me gustaría saber como corregir el color de las lineas ya que aunque se lo detallase en el código estas siguen sin aparecer como yo quiero.

También me gustaría saber como hacer que no se superponga por detrás la palabra wheezing.

He intentado buscar la solución a estos errores y no lo encuentro.
Gracia de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe un parámetro para establecer el color, `ggVennDiagram()` por defecto calcula un color automáticamente para cada elemento que determina un conjunto, sin embargo al tratarse en definitiva de un gráfico bajo la órbita de `ggplot`, es posible modificar el color por defecto, estableciendo por ejemplo una escala manual para los colores que cubra la cantidad de conjuntos, en tu caso son 4:

```
+ scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "blue", "red", "black"))
```

Con respecto al solapamiento de la etiqueta, puedo decirte que depende del tamaño del plot, si ajustas el panel de plot o haces un zoom y ajustas el tamaño de la ventana, esto se soluciona.

Ejemplo:

```
x <- list(A=1:5,B=2:7,C=3:6,D=4:9)
ggVennDiagram(
  x, label_alpha = 0,
  category.names = c("Cough","Sputum","Dyspnea", "Wheezing"),
  color = c('orange', 'green', 'blue','red')
  ) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient(low="white",high = "grey") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "blue", "red", "black"))
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona perfectamente Patricio, muchas gracias